# I'm trying to access a specific sheet inside a spreadsheet with google api, but it says "error: Unable to parse range", how do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets, google-api, spreadsheet

The sheet name is Tournament 1 - Completed.  I am not sure why it is giving me this error.  Also, would I be able to have an array of strings as the ranges value (Ex: ['Tournament 1 - Completed!A3:K', 'Tournament 2 - Completed!A3:K'])?

```
var completedTournaments = ['Tournament 1 - Completed!A3:K'];
var params = {
    spreadsheetId: id,
    ranges: completedTournaments,
    includeGridData: true,
};
var request = gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.get(params);
```

Comment: I think that your script is correct. And also, you can use the array as the range in this case. But, for example, when `['Tournament 1 - Completed!A3:K', 'Tournament 2 - Completed!A3:K']` is modified to `["'Tournament 1 - Completed'!A3:K", "'Tournament 2 - Completed'!A3:K"]`, the error message will be changed?

Comment: @Tanaike I tried that but it gives the same error message.  I also tried changing the name of the sheet to Sheet1 and the ranges to ['Sheet1!A3:K'] but it doesnt work.  Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortuantely, from your script in your question, I cannot find the modification points. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So in order to correctly understand about your current issue, can you provide  the detail flow for replicating your issue and the whole script without your personal information? By this, I would like to confirm your current issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Tanaike I think I was able to find the issue: I have a for loop that changes the id around the request.then(function(response) etc...

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: @Tanaike I found the issue but I am not really sure how to solve it.  I have a for loop which wraps around a changing id and a request to the google sheets but once inside the request the id doesnt change.  Do you know a solution to this? (I have the code to show but dont know how to put it here without it being in-line)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your script in your question and `I have a for loop which wraps around a changing id and a request to the google sheets but once inside the request the id doesnt change. Do you know a solution to this?`, unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Can you share the code where the error is originating? the for-loop you are talking about that changed the id